# My height attribute is showing different results in firefox than all the other browsers (safari,chrome act). Why?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a simple layout and the logo appears to be different in firefox and I can't seem to get an even medium in all browsers as when I change the height of the letter 'f' in the blue box it effects all browsers.

The issue i am having is with the div "logofoxfont" as I want the letter 'f' to be in the same position in all broswers but it appears to be different in firefox.

How can I sort this?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<link href="fw.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<div class="topbox">
<div class="logobox"><div class="logoboxfont">
f</div></div>
<div class="logotext"></div>
</div>
<div class="midbox">
<div class="menubox"><div class="menuboxfont">Home<br>About Us<br>Staff<br>News<br></div>
<div class="menubox2"><div class="menuboxfont2">Appointments<br>
Price Guide<br>Emergency Services<br>Feedback<br></div></div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the css is:

```
#logo{
background-image:url(40.jpg);
height:100px;
width:100px;
}

.topbox {
margin: 0px auto;
height:100px;
width:900px;
margin-top:0px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.logobox {
height:90px;
width:70px;
margin-top:10px;
background-color:#2FB2F4;
}

.logotext {
color: #333333;
font-family: Cambria;
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: -90px;
margin-left: 75px;
position:absolute;
}

#logotext1 {
margin-left:10px;
}

#logotext2 {
color: #00AAF5;
font-family: georgia;
font-size: 22px;
margin-top: -35px;
margin-left:10px;
}

.logoboxfont {
font-family:Cambria;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 126px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-left:0px;

-moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
-o-transform:rotate(10deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(10deg);
}

.midbox {
margin: 0px auto;
height:700px;
width:900px;
margin-top:0px;
background: #ffffff;
border-top: 1px solid #333333;
}

.menubox {
height:230px;
width:150px;
margin-top:10px;
background: #E6E6E6;
}

.menuboxfont {
color: #333333;
font-family:lucida grande;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left: 4px;
position:absolute;
}

.menubox2 {
height:160px;
width:150px;
margin-top:70px;
background: #FAFAFA;
position:absolute;
}

.menuboxfont2 {
color: #333333;
font-family:lucida grande;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left: 4px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

James

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: Your code looks the same to me in FF and Chrome, are you maybe zooming in under FF?

Comment: See my updated answer with images of chrome and safari. My fiddle is working in your desired browsers.

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle for code and demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHtmf/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kHtmf/1/embedded/result/

SS of Firefox:

[image]

SS of chrome:

[image]

SS of Safari:

[image]

Comment: yeah thats it but how can i make it look the same in firefox and safari and chrome? firefox is showing a different margin and height position. Is there a firefox stylesheet i can draw up?